# How to check if record exists in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, MS Sql Server and Windows 7 Ultimate

I'd like to know how to check if a certain record is already existing in the database so that I would avoid duplicate records. In rails it would have been easy to just invoke Object.exists? but I'm using Ruby only.

Thanks

Comment: you should use Primary/Unique keys on your table to avoid duplicate data!

Comment: yes. But for some reason I can't do that. So I'm trying to find a way to do it in ruby's way. Any ideas?

Comment: What ORM/library are you using? The answers depends on it.

Comment: I'm using Tiny_tds to connect to my database.

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code for [`exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists?) in activerecord

It basically checks if there `primary key` with the id exists already using sql query.

you can use these to write your own helper method.

or else u can also use `activerecord` gem in ruby too.